# Where is the result of fetch backbone?

Tags: javascript, api, backbone.js, parse-platform

I've fetched a collection in backbone by a apirest on parse.com but in the console.log i can read this result:
child {collection: child, attributes: Object, _escapedAttributes: Object, cid:   "c2",              changed: Object…}.

So where is the result??In my collection there are user with name,username ecc..

```
            var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

template: Handlebars.compile(template),

 events: {


  },

  initialize: function() {

      console.log("inhomeview");

      var amici = new Usercollection();
    amici.fetch({
  success: function(collection) {
   amici.each(function(object) {
  console.warn(object);
  console.log(object);
  });
  },
   error: function(amici, error) {
  // The collection could not be retrieved.
   }
   });
```

Collection:

```
     var Usercollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

     model:Person,
     url:'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/User',
```

Model:

```
       var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({


  defaults:{




      },


  initialize:function(){
          console.log("inperson");

      },

  validate:function(){
          console.log("validate");
      },

      send:function(){
           var user = new Parse.User();
           user.set("username", this.get("username"));
           user.set("password", this.get("password"));
           user.set("email", this.get("email"));

          // other fields can be set just like with Parse.Object
           //user.set("phone", "415-392-0202");

           user.signUp(null, {
           success: function(user) {
      // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
            },
           error: function(user, error) {
     // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
           alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
           }
         });


      }







         });




          return Person;
          });
```

Comment: Try `console.log(object.toJSON())`

Answer (score 1):

amici.models contains the objects you are pulling

each model is a Person

```
initialize: function() {
  var amici = new Usercollection();
  amici.fetch({
    success: function(collection) {
      amici.models.each(function(person) {
        console.log(person);
        console.log(person.attributes);
      });
    },
    error: function(amici, error) {
    }
  }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The objects you are printing to the console are instances of the `Person` model. That is what happens when you ask a collection to fetch data. It fetches data from the server, converts that data into model instances, and stores a list of those model instances as the collection contents. Perhaps you can further clarify your question.

Comment: I need to parse the result of collection with hanldebars.Now i've used Jsonstringify(object) and it returns a json array.It's right?

Comment: Now there is another problem,if i fetch by this url:https://api.parse.com/1/users return nothing,if i try to json stringify it make an empty array.Why?On parse.com user exists and contain some fields.

Comment: Don't use JSON.stringify. That is only needed when sending requests over the wire and backbone does that for you automatically. When you have a backbone collection and you want to convert it to plain data  objects (not a JSON string!) for rendering (not parsing) via handlebars, use `myCollection.toJSON()`, which will return an array of plain objects, which you can render via handlebars.